# What is the best way to obtain a ridiculously high score in Goat Ville?

Tags: goat-simulator

I just completed the challenge to get a "Big Ass Score" of 500000 (might be missing a zero or two), and it took nearly an hour of hunting down every high-scoring item to get there.

Now my challenge is 4x that big.

How in the name of Goat God can I get a score this high?

Or, in a more Arquade-friendly way, what are the highest-scoring bonuses that can be found in Goat Simulator, and which of them can be chained together to aid in score-building?

Comment: This question appears to be off topic because it is requesting assistance from caprine deities.

Comment: @PaulMarshall Well, the Biblical Stack Exchange turned me down....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried all of these methods today, with the latest version of Goat Simulator.

**Speeding Car Glitch: Patched :(** Tethering yourself to a car that is going off the map doesn't seem to help at this point.  I got no score whatsoever for glitching off the map using that method.  I also tried the truck and got nothing at all from that either.

**Low Gravity: Patched :(** The Low-Gravity room has been patched, so that now a "low-gravity" modifier is applied to the spins and flips you do in this room.  Thus, it is very, very unprofitable.

**Licking, Tricking, and Kicking In Dense Areas: Patched :(** The maximum multiplier has been capped, and after a short amount of time kicking, licking, and tricking in say, the convenience store by the gas station yields relatively low amounts of points.

**Science Hole: Improved Method!**  The Science Hole (which is in the hills near the low-gravity testing facility) is still a good place to do tricks.  However, I found that with the "low-gravity" mutator I was getting very low multipliers.  I could still do *massive* tricks, but I wouldn't get back down to the fan before my multiplier ran out.  This was still the fastest way to get points, however.

I found a trick that helps your point totals in the Science Hole.  Head over to Goathenge (which is across the field from the Science Hole) and lick a stone.  Take the stone back to the Science Hole.

[image: goats and stones may break my bones...]

It doesn't really matter what the stone is doing - it can be outside the hole, jammed in the hole, whatever, it doesn't make a difference.  Just make sure you're licking it.  Now try your Science Hole tricks:

[image: goathenge stone-lick]

There's a "while licking a goathenge stone" trick bonus, which is a massive benefit in this area.  Just use the standard trick methodology of holding two directions (ie, W and A) and occasionally release right mouse so you can reorient yourself over the hole.

Also, keep the "Jump" key pressed - sometimes when you hit the bottom, you'll wall run up the side, which increases the multiplier.  To stop wall running, release and then re-apply the jump button.

With this method, I was able to get several hundred thousand points in just a few minutes.

**Angel Goat Glide: OMGWTFGOAT** The "Angel Goat" mutator also gives you the ability to glide by holding R while in the air.  This wasn't clear until I saw the help text in the "Custom Game" screen.  With this, you can stay in the air far longer and get much bigger tricks.  You can also land on the ground safely, even from heights that would normally cause you to ragdoll and lose your combo.

You can use this to great effect via the following method:

- Get on top of the construction site (bonus points for licking a Goathenge stone up there as well, probably one of the Sanctum items would also qualify)
- Jump off the construction site and hold W, A, R, and the right mouse button
- Drift downward, aiming for the area right in front of the convenience store
- Once you land, QUICKLY Micheal Bay the gas pumps
- Jump through the convenience store window and smash everything therein - mix up tricks by head-butting, kicking, air head-butting, air-kicking, licking, hitting various people, jumping over things, etc
- Maybe do some wall runs or wall jumps if you are feeling frisky

Even just the jump itself is probably enough to get the highest score total.  Doing all this other stuff is likely to give you **over a billion points** with just this one combo.

The downside to the "R glide with Angel Goat" is that you can trick for so long that you overflow the score or something and end up with just 1 point from the trick.  So don't stay in the air tricking too long!

Comment: This is truly some epic science in the name of goat.

Comment: Pro tip on the Angel Goat Glide suggestion: Be careful while in the convenience store not to try to kick/headbutt too rapidly. A single accidental Manual that fails will destroy **your entire trick**.

Answer (score 7):

The best thing to do is to take a visit to the Low Gravity Testing Facility (found next to one of the tunnel entrances). You can either jump over the fence by the garage by jumping on the boxes stacked up next to it, or by climbing onto the sloped rocks by the goalposts and jumping over there, or walk though a hole in the fence by the gate (I only just noticed this...). Headbutt the brown panel to get yourself in, the walk up the slope to the right, enter the Low Gravity tank and go mental. Hold right-click and use the arrow keys to do front, side, and backflips, and the score will stack until you hit the ground, resulting in a ridiculously high score and something along the lines of a "Integer Overflowduple Backflip."

[image]

Do this a few times and you'll be there in no time.
[image]

Comment: I tried this, but I couldn't get my flip number any higher than a Hexagonuple.  What do you recommend for proper flip protocol?

Comment: I have actually tried this just yesterday and did not succeed in getting more than about 100 or so points each time, but I have seen it work for others in the past. My guess would be that this was patched.

Comment: I just held down the direction keys until I hit the ground.

Comment: When did you last try this?

Comment: I just tried this again and, indeed, it appears to have been patched. I've also tried licking the hang-glider, to no effect, and the rally car (which gets around 30/points per 10 seconds).

Comment: Yeah, they've actually made it quite difficult to get a high number of points. In addition, I believe they patched the fact that kicking different objects gives an additional multiplier past the first 5.

Answer (score 7):

Alright, so after some time spent researching in game. (Mostly consisting of jumping on and licking things. It looks like the quickest way to get a high score is to use the "Wonder Of Science" hole shown below similar to using a trampoline, in the fact that you constantly hold down right mouse button and two non-competing movement keys ((Aka w+d, a+w, a+s, s+d)) but with less likelihood of missing the fall back down. I was able to get several hundred thousand in a combo, and it can theoretically keep going higher. The one downside of using this is that you do have to keep adjusting your fall by letting go of the right mouse button somewhat, otherwise you'll ragdoll due to hitting the side of the top of the hole and be unable to continue your combo, but it's far easier to land back down on the fan inside than on a trampoline due to the walls.

[image]

Alternatively, a more fun, but very much less efficient method, generally resulting in 10000 - 40000 a shot is by glitching out the car that moves along the road. If you lick the car, it will take you into the tunnel, but keep you pressed against the back wall of the tunnel for a short time. Once the car disappears completely, you will go flying through the map, generally, as previously said, picking up a 10000-40000 score. You don't even have to lick the car while it's moving, as once in the tunnel, it'll stay just at the very edge of the tunnel for a short time, as shown below ((Brightness and contrast adjusted for maximum visibility)). It's hilarious to see what happens each time, but as mentioned, it's a lot less efficient than the first method.

[image]

Comment: Odd...the infinite spin technique for the zero-g room seems to have been patched.  What makes the Science Hole so effective?

Comment: So the reason the spinning doesn't work in the zero-g room, but works in the science hole is for two reasons. The first, is that in the zero-g room, it tacks on a 'low gravity' tag to your spins, reducing the point return. The second and more important is that the science hole doesn't send you up as high as a trampoline, allowing you to chain together a combo of spins, as your combo bar won't run out before you hit the fan again. It's actually very effective, as I said, I got a few hundred thousand points when I did it properly.

Comment: I'd recommend either trying it out yourself, else, I can upload an image of an actual combo from it tonight when I get home from work.

Comment: Interesting...I shall give it a try tonight.  If it works, you've just won yourself 100 rep.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, make sure you let go of right click for a second to move yourself back towards the center of the hole if you're against the wall and near max peak, else you'll hit your head on the wall and ragdoll.

Comment: I find it pretty hard to keep the goat centered while still performing mad flips, but this provides a higher point total than any other method listed here, so congratulations, Bounty Awarded.

Comment: By the way, do you recommend any goat in particular for this?

Comment: Not in particular. I honestly haven't really played much using any goat other than the base goat, as I feel the controls of all the others feel a little awkward.

Comment: Got it.  Note that I was using the Angel Goat, spinning as I came out of the science hole, then adjusting to land, then immediately hopping back in and spinning again.

Comment: Where is this hole?  I keep finding it and then losing it again...

Answer (score 4):

The trick I've found to getting points quickly is to get the Angel Goat mutator by not damaging anything for five minutes. There's also a spot in the Construction Site where there are mattresses on the ceiling and on the floor, which allow you to bounce insanely fast and get a crapload of points. Anyway, the Angel Goat mutator means that if you bounce off of fans and hold R, you stay airborne for a stupidly long time. If you hold A and W and RMB, you can get ridiculous numbers of points when you land.

Comment: So basically, either spin around while boucing on the up/down mattresses, or just launch yourself high into the air and use Angel Goat to float/spin to rack up points?  Not bad...but I fear the multiplier wouldn't be very good for the second one.  And that it would eventually wear out on the first.  Not a bad idea though.

Answer (score 1):

If tombull's answer has been patched, one of the best ways to get a high score is to go to a location with a large number of items in a confined place, and start kicking, licking and headbutting everything. You should be able to get up to a 15x multiplier each time for each of these actions. Alternatively, you can try looking for areas with repeatable 'purple' score modifiers, as these tend to give a larger number of points, and try and chain these with flips, headbutts, kicks, and licks, to try and combine the large number of points from purple score modifiers with high multipliers. The big issue with this is that most repeatable 'purple' score modifiers are in places where there's not much else around, so chaining these together can be quite difficult.

Alternatively, Goat Simulator is a very buggy game, and it is possible to glitch out to start racking up massive amounts of points. I had a glitch occur where I was able to keep getting 24x combos with about 10-15 'purple' score modifiers just by being stuck in the air. I've tried to replicate this glitch, but have been unsuccessful thus far. Just keep an eye out for this kind of thing happening while you play, and take full advantage of it when you can.

Comment: I have had some success with these methods - the convenience store attached to the gas station is particularly good, since it contains a ton of unique items that can allow you to rack up a huge multiplier.  The garage just outside the spawn point is also good, since you can drag a heavy object in front of the treadmill and ride it three times before wearing out the multiplier, then wreak havock on the items inside the garage...I ought to try dragging a bunch of things into one of these locations and going hog-wild.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they patched the fact that kicking and headbutting different objects increases your multiplier past the first 5 unfortunately. It's now incredibly difficult to get up to even a 20x multiplier.

Comment: Unless they did it literally today, I've found that it's the best way to get a multiplier score. But you DO need to have an insane number of differetn objects in your vicinity to get it past x20...or just be able to run to another location in the map by holding shift before your multiplier chance expires.

Comment: I shall experiment tonight and see if I can find a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Way too simple.

Use custom map, add Feather mutator.
Being an ostritch lick anything and keep it licked.
Jump straight up (preferably in a cleared area) and hold right mouse button, all the while you hit either A for left or D for right.
And Keep stupidly jumping.

If you time it right, the ostritch will not touch the foor, thereby givin you more spins.

Do this several times untill you touch the floor, then it wil say something like;
48907 points
6087 spin x1

That is when you make sure to touch the floor so the x1 becomes x10 or even x15.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this exists on the PC version, but on the IOS version, there is a cafe at the edge of the ocean, at the bottom of the tower. In there, you can find slot machines. When the game tells you to press your special move key, do so. If three of the same pieces are aligned, you will get a 1 000 000 point bonus that you can then easily multiply. The images align roughly 1/3 times, and the thing takes 10 seconds to spin, so can easily rack up 50 million points in two  or three minutes.

Comment: This appears to be advice for Goat City, not Goat Ville.