# What is the best way to obtain a ridiculously high score in Goat City Bay?

Tags: goat-simulator

[Previously](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/163331/what-is-the-best-way-to-obtain-a-ridiculously-high-score-in-goat-city) on Goat Simulator...

So there's a new map out for Goat Simulator.  New areas to explore, new civilians to terrorize, and most importantly, new ways to rack up sicknasty point totals.

Previously I had asked for the best way to rack up points on the original map.  Now, I'm asking if there are any wonderful tricks to abuse on THIS map to get incredibly high scores.

Note that it doesn't necessarily have to be *better* than the tricks in Goat City, but it should be effective enough to complete the 'Knocking Hard' goal by itself, as in the previous question.

Comment: Maybe the whale out in the ocean? I don't know much about goat sim. but after watching a few videos, the whale will launch you far out if you walk on it's blowhole.

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms That wont' help much.  Air will only get you so many points.

Comment: Like I said, I don't know much about goat sim. I just watch the videos.

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms Basically, just imagine Tony Hawk's Pro Skater, but with goats, and more broken parts.

Comment: That. Sounds. GLORIOUS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maddux is on the right track suggesting a big jump with the "angel" mutator.  I've got some additional tips that should help, though.

For quickest results, start a custom game on Goat City Bay with the Angel Goat mutator turned on.

There are several high points on this map you can start from:

- The wind turbines, which are high and on the right from where you start
- The dam, which is high and to the left from where you start
- The roof of the big hotel down by the water, you can enter through the front and take the elevator to the top, where Deadmau5 is holding a concert

From one of these places, jump off **towards as much land as you can** - it's critical that you land on the land and not in the water.

Now, hold **W, A, R, and the right mouse button** and you ought to start doing one super, super long trick.  If you need to adjust your trajectory, release the right mouse button and use W/A/S/D to move yourself.  You can release the R button for short periods to increase your downward momentum, if you've been in the air for too long.  Just make sure you're holding it as you start to land.

As you get close to the ground, release the right mouse button while holding the rest (W, A, and R).  This will auto-level you so that you land on your feet.  If you've been in the air tricking long enough, you shouldn't need to do any other combos.  One jump was enough to max out the score totals for me.

[image: flipping goat]

That's 143 million points, with no combo bonus or anything.  Presumably you could get some insane points by kicking your way through a house or shop, or doing a wall run or some additional tricks of some kind.  It's completely unnecessary, though.

If you want *even more* points, lick one of the following objects:

- The Wind Statue, which is on top of the middle wind turbine at the wind farm
- The "42" towel, which can be found by jumping down from the roof of the hotel, towards the water.  It's on the edge of the pool on the ledge midway down the side of the hotel.
- A whale, which you can summon with R once you've taken the 42 towel to the alien ship high above the dam

If you're actively licking one of these objects while you do your tricks, you'll get a bonus, just like you did while licking Goathenge [in my previous answer.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/174255/13845)  There are likely other things that would qualify, but these ones are easy to describe.

Comment: Is it hold R for floating as angel goat, or tap R once to float?

Comment: @Zibbobz, hold R for sure.  It's not a toggle like some R powers are.  Letting go of R causes you to fall normally again.  Tapping it will slow your descent, but it's much safer to hold.  I didn't know this was an effect of Angel Goat until I saw it on the "custom game" screen.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Putin Hotel and go to the roof party. You have to have angel goat to do this. To unlock him, you must not hurt anyone for 5 minutes straight. I recommend just sitting there for five minutes.

Once you have him and are up there, go straight across from the elevator and get on the slanted roof. Now jump, but make sure you press R at the top of your jump, so you float slowly.

While doing this, do as many flips as possible. If you don't know how to do this, hold down right click and press the WASD buttons repeatedly.  Once you think you've done enough, make sure you're upright and carefully tap R and land safely on the bottom. Once landed, build up a combo by doing other tricks in the nearby area. The points you get combined with the large jump and number of flips you did should get you a lot of points.

Answer (score 1):

If you play on the console versions, it is much easier to do flips in midair, as the joystick can be moved quickly and accurately. As any unlocked mutators can be applied at will on console, the best combo for score and air time is the Feather Goat (Ostrich), the Angel Goat, the Double Jump Goat, and the VR Goat (Double points woot). If you follow the other tips on this page, you should have no trouble getting absurd scores.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to get points is the casino in the back of the hotel. You press the pow button and it gives you somewhere around 1000000 points :)